# I want to start parsing json file in an specific position SWIFTUI

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, swiftui

I have this json and mi intention is to get the "municipios" array only.

```
{
  "title": "Municipios de Pontevedra",
  "provincia": "Pontevedra",
  "codprov": "36",
  "metadescripcion": "Lista de municipios de la provincia de Pontevedra | Seleccionar un muncipio",
  "keywords": "Lista de municipios, Previsión meteorológica para los municipios de la provincia de Pontevedra , El tiempo",
  "municipios": [
    {
      "CODIGOINE": "36001000000",
      "ID_REL": "1360010",
      "COD_GEO": "36010",
      "CODPROV": "36",
      "NOMBRE_PROVINCIA": "Pontevedra",
      "NOMBRE": "Arbo",
      "POBLACION_MUNI": 2904,
      "SUPERFICIE": 4266,
      "PERIMETRO": 33435,
      "CODIGOINE_CAPITAL": "36001011101",
      "NOMBRE_CAPITAL": "O Pazo",
      "POBLACION_CAPITAL": "286",
      "HOJA_MTN25": "0262-2",
      "LONGITUD_ETRS89_REGCAN95": -8.31474568,
      "LATITUD_ETRS89_REGCAN95": 42.11276572,
      "ORIGEN_COORD": "Mapa",
      "ALTITUD": 113,
      "ORIGEN_ALTITUD": "MDT5",
      "DISCREPANTE_INE": 0
    },
    {
      "CODIGOINE": "36002000000",
      "ID_REL": "1360025",
      "COD_GEO": "36020",
      "CODPROV": "36",
      "NOMBRE_PROVINCIA": "Pontevedra",
      "NOMBRE": "Barro",
      "POBLACION_MUNI": 3705,
      "SUPERFICIE": 3763.6494,
      "PERIMETRO": 31578,
      "CODIGOINE_CAPITAL": "36002041301",
      "NOMBRE_CAPITAL": "Santo Antoniño",
      "POBLACION_CAPITAL": "426",
      "HOJA_MTN25": "0152-4",
      "LONGITUD_ETRS89_REGCAN95": -8.62642506,
      "LATITUD_ETRS89_REGCAN95": 42.55592981,
      "ORIGEN_COORD": "Mapa",
      "ALTITUD": 143,
      "ORIGEN_ALTITUD": "MDT5",
      "DISCREPANTE_INE": 0
    },...
```

I have tried with this code but it gives me an error due to a problem with the array. I think this espects an array but the json is a dictionary since it starts with the { character, am i right?

```
import Foundation

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Municipio: Codable,Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let NOMBRE: String
    let POBLACION_MUNI: Int
}

class apiCall {
    func getMunicipios(completion:@escaping ([Municipio]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "urltojson") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let municipios = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Municipio].self, from: data!)
            print(municipios)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(municipios)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

My intention is to get just the array of "municipios"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66423755/how-to-create-a-struct-to-match-this-json/66424855#66424855

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode your stuff to this `Result` struct instead of `[Municipio]`

```
struct Result: Codable {
    var municipios: [Municipio]
    
    struct Municipio: Codable, Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let NOMBRE: String
        let POBLACION_MUNI: Int
    }
}
```

so you'll need to decode like this:

```
let municipiosResult = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data!)
// your municipios will be accessible like this:
let municipios = municipiosResult.municipios
print(municipios)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just decode an inner part of the structure without *also* decoding the outer part. So, you have to have a data structure that can handle the entire body of the JSON. Using `app.quicktype.io`, it generates this structure:

```
struct JSONBody: Codable {
    let title, provincia, codprov, metadescripcion: String
    let keywords: String
    let municipios: [Municipio]
}

struct Municipio: Codable {
    let codigoine, idRel, codGeo, codprov: String
    let nombreProvincia, nombre: String
    let poblacionMuni, superficie, perimetro: Int
    let codigoineCapital, nombreCapital, poblacionCapital, hojaMtn25: String
    let longitudEtrs89Regcan95, latitudEtrs89Regcan95: Double
    let origenCoord: String
    let altitud: Int
    let origenAltitud: String
    let discrepanteIne: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case codigoine = "CODIGOINE"
        case idRel = "ID_REL"
        case codGeo = "COD_GEO"
        case codprov = "CODPROV"
        case nombreProvincia = "NOMBRE_PROVINCIA"
        case nombre = "NOMBRE"
        case poblacionMuni = "POBLACION_MUNI"
        case superficie = "SUPERFICIE"
        case perimetro = "PERIMETRO"
        case codigoineCapital = "CODIGOINE_CAPITAL"
        case nombreCapital = "NOMBRE_CAPITAL"
        case poblacionCapital = "POBLACION_CAPITAL"
        case hojaMtn25 = "HOJA_MTN25"
        case longitudEtrs89Regcan95 = "LONGITUD_ETRS89_REGCAN95"
        case latitudEtrs89Regcan95 = "LATITUD_ETRS89_REGCAN95"
        case origenCoord = "ORIGEN_COORD"
        case altitud = "ALTITUD"
        case origenAltitud = "ORIGEN_ALTITUD"
        case discrepanteIne = "DISCREPANTE_INE"
    }
}
```

Which you can decode by doing something like this:

```
func decode(jsonData: Data) {
    do {
        let body = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONBody.self, from: jsonData)
        let municipos = body.municipios
        print(municipos)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `do/try/catch` and not `try!` -- `try!` will crash if it fails and won't give you useful information about *why* it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both, you really helped me by telling me I had to parse the whole document. This is my result code that works perfectly.

```
struct JSONObject: Codable {
    let title: String
    let provincia: String
    let codprov: String
    let metadescripcion: String
    let keywords: String
    let municipios: [Municipio]
}

struct Municipio: Codable,Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let CODIGOINE: String
    let NOMBRE: String
    let POBLACION_MUNI: Int
}

class Api {
    func getObject(completion:@escaping ([Municipio]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/36/municipios") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let objeto = try! JSONDecoder().decode(JSONObject.self, from: data!)
            let municipios = objeto.municipios
            print(municipios)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(municipios)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome ;). There is no obligation for you, but it would be nice if you upvoted the answers that you found useful using the up mark which is to the left of the answers. Also you can mark one of the answers which works better for you as the final Answer to your question. Again, there is no obligation, and thanks!

Comment: Make sure to check out my note about `try!` -- having that will crash your app if the server ever returns an unexpected result.